# How to Handle Cancelled Recurring Payments

Tags: paypal, payment, recurring

I'm using Paypal to handle automated recurring payments for my website.  Users pay to subscribe to my website so they can get periodic newsletters.

So let's say a customer cancels their membership a few months later.  They do this by logging into Paypal and cancels future automated payments.  How should I update my website to reflect this cancellation?

The first solution I'm thinking of is to schedule a cronjob that executes a script every midnight to update my database with information from Paypal.

The second solution is on newsletter mailout day, I execute a script to update my database with information from Paypal.  The website will also execute the script every time a user "logs in" to my website.

Are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, Paypal's servers will update yours automatically when the status of a subscription changes, if you have this configured. This is called IPN (Instant Payment Notification) and does indeed include cancellation notification. Here's the [Paypal documentation for recurring (subscription) payments](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPRecurringPayments#id086510570PN). Additionally you can poll their servers using their API for this information, so if you'd prefer to fetch it yourself, you can.

Comment: ah ok, let me research this then!

Comment: Just added a link to paypal's documentation. =)

Comment: I don't fully understand. Is the cancellation notification passed in the query string. How do yuo know that the payment notification refers to a cancellation of recurring payment?

Comment: @JohnMerlino for your better understanding, you can identify wheather notification refers to a cancellation, create profile or regular recurring payment is by the parameters sent in the IPN.                  If $_REQUEST['txn_type'] == 'recurring_payment_profile_cancel' then its for profile cancelled and if $_POST['txn_type'] == 'recurring_payment_profile_created' then its for profile created , if $_POST['period_type']) == 'Regular' && $_POST['payment_status'] == 'Completed' then it means you have recieved a regular recurring payment.